# ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension-KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, knn

Nearest neighbor and I have got this error: ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension.

how can I figure out the dimensions of the classifier and how can I fix this

here is my code if anyone can help :

```
# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the training set

dataset = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Train1.csv')
X_train = dataset.iloc[:, 0:1].values
y_train = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


# Importing testing set
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Test1.csv')
X_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, :-1].values
y_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, -1].values


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)




# KNN 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)






y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `X_train` and `X_test` must have same features. 
So, change `X_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, :-1].values` to `X_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, 0:1].values` as you did for `X_train`.

In addition, most preprocessing models including scaler should be fitted using train data and they are used to transform both train and test data.

So, change the code as follows.

before

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
```

after

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because of inconsistency in dimension of `X_train` and `X_test`.

`X_train` has the only one column as you have used `X_train = dataset.iloc[:,`**0:1**`]`.values instead of `X_train = dataset.iloc[:,` **:-1**`]`.values. So your train data have only 1 feature and test data have n features. You can use `DataFrame.shape() (X_train.shape())` for checking shape of your dataframes.

There is another problem that will cause the poor performance of your model in production i.e [data leakage](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-leakage-in-machine-learning-10bdd3eec742).

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
```

Here you are using mean and std of train data for the train data scaling and of test data for the test data scaling. But this will cause data leakage issue. To prevent this issue use the below approach.
Calculate mean and std from train dataset and then apply that to train and test

```
sc.fit(X_train) # python will calculate std and mean save it internally
X_train = sc.transform(X_train) #scaling train dataset
X_test = sc.transform(X_test )  #scaling test datset
```

You can replace first 2 lines with `X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)`. I have written in 2 steps for more clarification.